# Plymouth not showing after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, plymouth

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 today, the Plymouth splash screen is not showing when I startup my computer.  The screen goes purple at first, then goes black and I am shown the Login Screen.

It showed up when the computer shuts down, though.

Is there a way to make plymouth show again?

Comment: try typing sudo update-initramfs –u in the terminal then reboot

Comment: @StephenMyall  I tried that but it didn't work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initial Purple Boot Screen is text not Image in 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202649/initial-purple-boot-screen-is-text-not-image-in-12-10)

Comment: @Mitch I don't think it's a duplicate. This OP wants it fixed, while the other is just asking if there is anything wrong.

Comment: @Mitch My screen shows nothing while the other guy had a text plymouth.

Comment: @EmersonHsieh: Did you try pressing <ctrl><alt><F7> during boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following to fix the problem on my machine:
(found at http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2066656.html)

1. gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
2. add the following line making sure to put in your native resolution in place of 1680x1050:
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="1680x1050"
3. sudo update-grub

Comment: This worked for me. Definitely an nVidia driver issue. If I upgrade to EXPERIMENTAL drivers it corrects the problem, however recovering from STANDBY breaks. Thank very much @krumpelstiltskin for posting the solution...